# C# Pack 5 integers into 1

Tags: c#, integer, bit, pack

I'm trying to pack, and unpack, 5 integers ( max 999 for each ) into a single unique integer using bit shift operations:

```
static UInt64 Combine(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e)
    {
        return (a << 48) | (b << 32 ) | (c << 16) | (d << 8) | e;
    }
```

However, I am unable to unpack the number back.
Can anyone please guide me to what I could be doing wrong ? 
thanks.

Comment: If you don't show us what you're doing to try to unpack them, how can we tell you what you're doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need 10 bits to pack 0-999. 8 bits only gets you to 255. 10 bits will get you to 1023.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to pack the values `0..999`, you need *ten* bits, not eight. Ten will give you the values `0..1023` whereas eight will only give you `0..255`.

So the function you need is something like:

```
static UInt64 Combine(
    uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e
) {
    UInt64 retval = a;
    retval = (retval << 10) | b;
    retval = (retval << 10) | c;
    retval = (retval << 10) | d;
    retval = (retval << 10) | e;
    return retval;
}
```

Then, to unpack them, just extract each group of ten bits, one at a time, such as:

```
static void Extract(UInt64 val, out uint a, out uint b,
    out uint c, out uint d, out uint e
) {
    e = Convert.ToUInt32(val & 0x3ff); val = val >> 10;
    d = Convert.ToUInt32(val & 0x3ff); val = val >> 10;
    c = Convert.ToUInt32(val & 0x3ff); val = val >> 10;
    b = Convert.ToUInt32(val & 0x3ff); val = val >> 10;
    a = Convert.ToUInt32(val & 0x3ff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of storing numbers.  It's a little different.  But, I thought I'd present it to you.  Basically, we're just emulating "Unions":

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Unions
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        struct uShortArray
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public ushort Bytes01;
            [FieldOffset(2)]
            public ushort Bytes23;
            [FieldOffset(4)]
            public ushort Bytes45;
            [FieldOffset(6)]
            public ushort Bytes67;

            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public long long1;
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            uShortArray ua = default(uShortArray);
            ua.Bytes01 = 999;
            ua.Bytes23 = 164;
            ua.Bytes45 = 581;
            ua.Bytes67 = 43;

            MessageBox.Show($"ua = [Bytes 0 - 1 : {ua.Bytes01}] ... [Byte 2 - 3 : {ua.Bytes23}] ... [Bytes 4 - 5 : {ua.Bytes45}] ... [Bytes 6 - 7 : {ua.Bytes67}] ... [long1 : {ua.long1}]");

            uShortArray ua2 = default(uShortArray);

            Combine(out ua2, 543, 657, 23, 999);

            MessageBox.Show($"ua2 = [Bytes 0 - 1 : {ua2.Bytes01}] ... [Byte 2 - 3 : {ua2.Bytes23}] ... [Bytes 4 - 5 : {ua2.Bytes45}] ... [Bytes 6 - 7 : {ua2.Bytes67}] ... [long1 : {ua2.long1}]");

            uShortArray ua3 = default(uShortArray);
            ua3.long1 = ua.long1;  //As you can see, you don't need an extract.  You just assign the "extract" value to long1.

            MessageBox.Show($"ua3 = [Bytes 0 - 1 : {ua3.Bytes01}] ... [Byte 2 - 3 : {ua3.Bytes23}] ... [Bytes 4 - 5 : {ua3.Bytes45}] ... [Bytes 6 - 7 : {ua3.Bytes67}] ... [long1 : {ua3.long1}]");
        }

        private void Combine(out uShortArray inUA, ushort in1, ushort in2, ushort in3, ushort in4)
        {
            inUA = default(uShortArray);

            inUA.Bytes01 = in1;
            inUA.Bytes23 = in2;
            inUA.Bytes45 = in3;
            inUA.Bytes67 = in4;
        }
    }
}
```

This struct only stores 4 values.  But, you can use a larger type, instead of long, to hold more numbers.